# Dynamics 2011 CRM - Visual Studio Developer Tools / Org Mismatch

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I'm creating a CRM 2011 plug-in.  I created it with the Visual Studio Solution Template for Dynamics 2011, and authored it as a CRM 2011 Plug-In Library.  After completing the iniital implementation  and testing in CRM, I now need to associate the plugin with a different Entity / Attribute / SDK Message.  So...I re-opened VS to try to create another plug-in or to otherwise edit it this one.

Oddly, I get a WCF Error from Visual Studio's IDE when I re-start an existing SLN that *used to work*.  Specifically, I get the error when I start the CRM Explorer in VS.  The error is pretty generic -

> The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error. etc .etc.

The CRM Explorer tree shows 0 Entities and 0 Option Sets after the error, though the other tree nodes seem to have the correct content.  It feels to me that something in my Org or CRM Server has broken the VS integration, but don't have any idea what that might have been.  I mean I hadn't made any changes to the Org at all in a week or so (though I did apply August Windows Updates!).  I'm on Cum Update 8 at the moment.

When I delete the hidden blah.SUO and the blah.docstates.suo files, and restart VS ... the CRM Explorer prompts for my server / credentials / Org as expected for the initial start.  However, I get the above WCF error again and the CRM Explorer does not populate correctly following this "reset".  I have also tried uninstalling the CRM Developer Toolkit without luck.

Anyone seen this behavior before, or have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen something like that happen when the WCF endpoints were re-configured (CRM Deployment Manager).  You can check to see what the endpoints are in the Settings - Customizations - Developer Resources

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue: trying to connect to CRM Server through development toolkit add-in to VS.

**Resolution**: add the user to the CRM Organisation and assign role "System Administrator".